# Creating JDBC functions from corresponding WSDL

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, wsdl

I am working on building a web service from scratch with JDBC for postgreSQL. thing is that the `operations` given in the wsdl file do not show the corresponding database relation (Schema was provided by the client). i.e. for a `message` like

`message name="loginRequest">

part name="in0" type="xsd:string"/>

part name="in1" type="xsd:string"/>

/message>`

I cannot find out the corresponding column or what the parameters map on to.
Any solution?

P.S.I had to remove "<"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC is an interface for databases. It can be used for both WebService server and client, but it cannot be used to parse WebService queries etc. You will have to use other library/technology like [axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/).

In axis2 there is [wsdl2java](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#WSDL2JavaBuildingStubsSkeletonsAndDataTypesFromWSDL) utility which can create server or client code "skeleton". In those sources you can use JDBC libraries to make database queries.